# Appium Inspector Not Working Unable to inspect the element in ios 15.3.1

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

Iam using xcode v-13.2 appium version 1.21.0 and iPhone XR v-15.3.1 not able to open appium inspector pls help!!!!

terminal code-
Last login: Fri Feb 25 01:09:02 on ttys000
taniya@Anus-MacBook ~ % cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
taniya@Anus-MacBook appium-webdriveragent % xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id='00008020-000E08901EF9002E' test -allowProvisioningUpdates
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=00008020-000E08901EF9002E test -allowProvisioningUpdates

```
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    2022-02-25 01:13:10.330 xcodebuild[9152:471315] CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    Analyze workspace
    
    Create build description
    Build description signature: 41cbaf1fe2310278fb3c9a049f6b7dc8
    Build description path: /Users/Taniya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/41cbaf1fe2310278fb3c9a049f6b7dc8-desc.xcbuild
    
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    Testing started
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.528951+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Running tests...
    Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2022-02-25 01:13:13.949
    Test Suite 'WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest' started at 2022-02-25 01:13:13.949
    Test Suite 'UITestingUITests' started at 2022-02-25 01:13:13.950
        t =      nans Suite Set Up
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.981084+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        KeyboardAutocorrection
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.981636+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        "KeyboardAutocorrection_changedAt"
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.982059+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        "KeyboardAutocorrection_buildAtChange"
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.982425+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        "KeyboardAutocorrection_previousValue"
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.982751+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        "KeyboardAutocorrection_analyzedAt"
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.990357+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        KeyboardPrediction
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.990775+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        KeyboardShowPredictionBar
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.991318+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
        DidShowGestureKeyboardIntroduction
    ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x280582a00> (Domain: com.apple.keyboard.preferences, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
    Test Case '-[UITestingUITests testRunner]' started.
        t =     0.00s Start Test at 2022-02-25 01:13:13.992
        t =     0.00s Set Up
    2022-02-25 01:13:13.993946+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Built at Feb 25 2022 01:09:15
    2022-02-25 01:13:14.009294+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] ServerURLHere->http://192.168.101.4:8100<-ServerURLHere
    2022-02-25 01:13:14.010070+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487639] Using singleton test manager
    2022-02-25 01:18:25.473278+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
        t =   311.50s Find the Application 'com.apple.springboard'
        t =   311.51s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
    2022-02-25 01:18:26.519103+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
        t =   312.53s Find the Application 'com.apple.springboard'
        t =   312.53s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
    2022-02-25 01:18:26.656315+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
        t =   312.67s Get all elements bound by accessibility element for: Descendants matching type StatusBar
        t =   312.67s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
        t =   312.77s     Find: Descendants matching type StatusBar
        t =   312.78s Checking existence of `StatusBar`
        t =   312.78s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
        t =   312.87s     Find: Descendants matching type StatusBar
        t =   312.87s     Find: Identity Binding
        t =   312.87s Find the StatusBar
        t =   312.88s     Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
        t =   312.96s     Find: Descendants matching type StatusBar
        t =   312.96s     Find: Identity Binding
    2022-02-25 01:18:26.974700+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
        t =   312.98s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.074784+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.087328+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
        t =   313.10s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.191684+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.217950+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Getting the most recent active application (out of 1 total items)
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.221305+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] The following attributes were requested to be included into the XML: {(
        FBNameAttribute,
        FBHeightAttribute,
        FBAccessibleAttribute,
        FBValueAttribute,
        FBVisibleAttribute,
        FBWidthAttribute,
        FBEnabledAttribute,
        FBTypeAttribute,
        FBYAttribute,
        FBLabelAttribute,
        FBIndexAttribute,
        FBXAttribute
    )}
    2022-02-25 01:18:27.221497+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1296:487378] Waiting up to 2s until com.apple.springboard is in idle state (including animations)
        t =   313.23s Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
        t =   313.23s Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 63
    
    
    
    
    attaching images of iphone,appium,and inspector-
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz58Y.png
appium code-

The server is running
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.21.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions
[HTTP] {}
[GENERIC] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []
[GENERIC] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 5 ms - 40
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"NoReset":true,"autoLaunch":false,"automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.mcdonalds.gma.Arch","deviceName":"iPhone XR","fullReset":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"14.7","udid":"00008020-000E08901EF9002E","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"NoReset":true,"autoLaunch":false,"automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.mcdonalds.gma.Arch","deviceName":"iPhone XR","fullReset":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"14.7","udid":"00008020-000E08901EF9002E","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,null]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1645732104338 (01:18:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Appium v1.21.0 creating new XCUITestDriver (v3.43.0) session
[Appium] Applying relaxed security to 'XCUITestDriver' as per server command line argument. All insecure features will be enabled unless explicitly disabled by --deny-insecure
[BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {
[BaseDriver]   "NoReset": true,
[BaseDriver]   "autoLaunch": false,
[BaseDriver]   "automationName": "XCUITest",
[BaseDriver]   "bundleId": "com.mcdonalds.gma.Arch",
[BaseDriver]   "deviceName": "iPhone XR",
[BaseDriver]   "fullReset": false,
[BaseDriver]   "platformName": "iOS",
[BaseDriver]   "platformVersion": "14.7",
[BaseDriver]   "udid": "00008020-000E08901EF9002E",
[BaseDriver]   "newCommandTimeout": 0,
[BaseDriver]   "connectHardwareKeyboard": true
[BaseDriver] }
[BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
[BaseDriver]   NoReset
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856
[XCUITest] Current user: 'taniya'
[XCUITest] Available devices: 00008020-000E08901EF9002E
[XCUITest] Creating iDevice object with udid '00008020-000E08901EF9002E'
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '00008020-000E08901EF9002E', real device: true
[BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1645732105240 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1645732105241 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'resetStarted' logged at 1645732105241 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Reset: running ios real device reset flow
[BaseDriver] Event 'resetComplete' logged at 1645732105241 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA path: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent'
[WebDriverAgent] Using WDA agent: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[XCUITest] Crash reports root '/Users/Taniya/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/Anu’s iPhone' does not exist. Got nothing to gather.
[BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1645732105481 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Setting up real device
[WebDriverAgent] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[DevCon Factory] Requesting connection for device 00008020-000E08901EF9002E on local port 8100, device port 8100
[DevCon Factory] Cached connections count: 0
[DevCon Factory] Successfully requested the connection for 00008020-000E08901EF9002E:8100
[XCUITest] Starting WebDriverAgent initialization with the synchronization key 'XCUITestDriver'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"message":"WebDriverAgent is ready to accept commands","state":"success","os":{"testmanagerdVersion":28,"name":"iOS","sdkVersion":"15.2","version":"15.3.1"},"ios":{"ip":"192.168.101.4"},"ready":true,"build":{"time":"Feb 25 2022 01:09:15","productBundleIdentifier":"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"}},"sessionId":null}
[WebDriverAgent] Upgrade timestamp of the currently bundled WDA: 1620631774000
[WebDriverAgent] Upgrade timestamp of the WDA on the device: undefined
[WebDriverAgent] Will reuse previously cached WDA instance at 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/' with 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'. Set the wdaLocalPort capability to a value different from 8100 if this is an undesired behavior.
[XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 1 times with 10000ms interval
[XCUITest] These values can be customized by changing wdaStartupRetries/wdaStartupRetryInterval capabilities
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1645732105769 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[WebDriverAgent] Using provided WebdriverAgent at 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"message":"WebDriverAgent is ready to accept commands","state":"success","os":{"testmanagerdVersion":28,"name":"iOS","sdkVersion":"15.2","version":"15.3.1"},"ios":{"ip":"192.168.101.4"},"ready":true,"build":{"time":"Feb 25 2022 01:09:15","productBundleIdentifier":"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"}},"sessionId":null}
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1645732105781 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true,"shouldTerminateApp":true}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":" ","sdkVersion":"15.3.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.springboard"}},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[WD Proxy] Determined the downstream protocol as 'W3C'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1645732105983 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1645732105983 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if this is an undesired behavior.
[BaseDriver] Event 'orientationSet' logged at 1645732105984 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[BaseDriver] The value of 'elementResponseAttributes' setting did not change. Skipping the update for it
[BaseDriver] The value of 'shouldUseCompactResponses' setting did not change. Skipping the update for it
[Appium] New XCUITestDriver session created successfully, session f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856 added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1645732105985 (01:18:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Cached the protocol value 'MJSONWP' for the new session f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"NoReset":true,"autoLaunch":false,"automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.mcdonalds.gma.Arch","deviceName":"iPhone XR","fullReset":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"14.7","udid":"00008020-000E08901EF9002E","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 1648 ms - 544
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/contexts
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getContexts() with args: ["f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getContexts'
[XCUITest] Getting list of available contexts
[iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
[XCUITest] Selecting by url: false 
[RemoteDebugger] Remote Debugger version 8.13.2
[RemoteDebugger] useNewSafari --> false
[RemoteDebugger] Checking which communication style to use (non-Safari on platform version '14.7')
[RemoteDebugger] Platform version equal or higher than '12.2': true
[RemoteDebugger] Setting communication protocol: using Target-based communication
[RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request
[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 0): 'setConnectionKey'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 3ms
[RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request
[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 2): 'setConnectionKey'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 3ms
[RemoteDebugger] Selecting application
[RemoteDebugger] No applications currently connected.
[XCUITest] No web frames found.
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/contexts 200 186 ms - 86
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/context
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getCurrentContext() with args: ["f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getCurrentContext'
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.getCurrentContext() result: "NATIVE_APP"
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/context 200 2 ms - 84
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getSession() with args: ["f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getSession'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'getSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":" ","sdkVersion":"15.3.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.springboard"}},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /wda/screen] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/wda/screen] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"statusBarSize":{"width":414,"height":48},"scale":2},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/window/size] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"width":414,"height":896},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[XCUITest] Merging WDA caps over Appium caps for session detail response
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.getSession() result: {"udid":"00008020-000E08901EF9002E","NoReset":true,"autoLaunch":false,"automationName":"XCUITest","bundleId":"com.mcdonalds.gma.Arch","deviceName":"iPhone XR","fullReset":false,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"14.7","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true,"device":"iphone","browserName":" ","sdkVersion":"15.3.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.springboard","pixelRatio":2,"statBarHeight":48,"viewportRect":{"left":0,"top":96,"width":828,"height":1696}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856 200 582 ms - 546
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/window/current/size
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowSize() with args: ["current","f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getWindowSize'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /window/size] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/window/size] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"width":414,"height":896},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.getWindowSize() result: {"width":414,"height":896}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/window/current/size 200 117 ms - 98
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/execute
[HTTP] {"script":"mobile:getContexts","args":[]}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["mobile:getContexts",[],"f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'execute'
[XCUITest] Getting list of available contexts
[iOS] Retrieving contexts and views
[XCUITest] Selecting by url: false 
[RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request
[RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message (id: 4): 'setConnectionKey'
[RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 1ms
[RemoteDebugger] Selecting application
[RemoteDebugger] No applications currently connected.
[XCUITest] No web frames found.
[XCUITest] No webviews found in 1ms
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.execute() result: [{"id":"NATIVE_APP"}]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/execute 200 3 ms - 93
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/source
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getPageSource'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/source' to command name 'getPageSource'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /source] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/source] with no body
[WebDriverAgent] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/Taniya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Build/Products'
[WebDriverAgent] Got derived data root: '/Users/Taniya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp'
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":"\n\n  \n    \n      \n    \n    \n  \n  
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Responding to client with driver.getPageSource() result: "\n  \n    \n      \n    \n    \n  \n  
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/source 200 1759 ms - 20029
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/screenshot
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'getScreenshot'
[XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/screenshot] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen
[XCUITest] Error getting screenshot: A screen capture was made impossible
[XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/screenshot] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen
[XCUITest] Taking screenshot with WDA
[WD Proxy] Matched '/screenshot' to command name 'getScreenshot'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/session/AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189/screenshot] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"unable to capture screen","message":"A screen capture was made impossible","traceback":""},"sessionId":"AB8BF474-27EB-4C78-978E-83EBBAC4F189"}
[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'unable to capture screen' to UnableToCaptureScreen
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)] Encountered internal error running command: UnableToCaptureScreen: A screen capture was made impossible
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)]     at errorFromW3CJsonCode (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:780:25)
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)]     at ProxyRequestError.getActualError (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:663:14)
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)]     at JWProxy.command (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:272:19)
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)]     at runMicrotasks ()
[MJSONWP (f3731b63)]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/f3731b63-8e2e-4be1-9c50-3f5774a79856/screenshot 500 1043 ms - 123
[HTTP] 

pls help
```